# Sliding images with animation in ngx-bootstrap for angular 5

Tags: angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap carousel for sliding my images in mainpage. How can i sliding images with animation?

Comment: Please introduce if you know another package.

Comment: There's no animation support in ngx-bootstrap now

Comment: https://github.com/sheikalthaf/ngx-carousel - this one has animation support but I haven't worked with it yet so can't say anything about its pros and cons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/281

in CSS component i added

```
.animated {
   -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 1;}
}
.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}
```

in html i added

```
<carousel>
  <slide class="animated fadeIn">
    <img src="xxx.xx" class="carousel-img">
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

Answer (score 7):

To create sliding animation I've came up with next solution

in main `styles.scss` add

```css
carousel.slide-animated {
  slide.item {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    &.active {
      width: 100%;
      animation-name: carouselSlideIn;
    }
    &:not(.active) {
      display: table-cell;
      animation-name: carouselSlideOut;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes carouselSlideIn {
  0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
@keyframes carouselSlideOut {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

You can use it than in component like:

```html
<carousel class="slide-animated">
  <slide><img src="slide1.jpg"/></slide>
  <slide><img src="slide2.jpg"/></slide>
  <slide><img src="slide3.jpg"/></slide>
</carousel>
```

PS: The single problem left is that slides are always moving from right to left, no matter which arrow you've pressed. I will update answer when/if I resolve this

Answer (score 0):

grigson i found the solution for your problem

outside my carousel element i created two different div that calls a method when you mouseover then

that method change the state of two variables (to true and false)

and my carousel component has 2 class bindings, one for next and other for prev

so my html looks like this

```
<div class="list" style="margin: auto;max-width: 1500px;">
<div class="prev" (mouseenter)="onPrev()" >

</div>
<div class="next" (mouseenter)="onNext()" >

</div>
<carousel
[class.slide-animated-next]="next"
[class.slide-animated-prev]="prev"
[showIndicators]="false"
[itemsPerSlide]="6"
[noWrap]="false"
[interval]="50000"
style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">

<slide *ngFor="let product of list" style="margin: 1rem">
  <app-card-no-brand-partial [imgProduto]="product.img" 
    [nomeProduto]="product.nome" [precoProduto]="product.preco">
  </app-card-no-brand-partial>
</slide>
```

my css

```
carousel.slide-animated-next
 slide.item
   animation-duration: 0.5s
   animation-fill-mode: both
  &.active
   animation-name: carouselSlideIn

carousel.slide-animated-prev
 slide.item
   animation-duration: 0.5s
   animation-fill-mode: both
  &.active
   animation-name: carouselSlideOut



  @keyframes carouselSlideIn
   0%
     transform: translateX(-600%)
   100%
     transform: translateX(0)


  @keyframes carouselSlideOut
   0%
    transform: translateX(600%)
   100%
    transform: translateX(0%)

  .prev
   z-index: 20000
   position: absolute
   width: 50%
   height: 400px
   margin-left: -5%



  .next
   z-index: 20000
   position: absolute
   width: 50%
   height: 400px

   margin-left: 50%
```

and finally my typescript has this;

```
  prev: boolean;
  next: boolean;

  onNext() {
   this.next = true;
   this.prev = false;
  }
  onPrev() {
   this.prev = true;
   this.next = false;
  }
```

and in your styles.css you need

```
.carousel-control-prev,
.carousel-control-next
 z-index: 20000
```

to put the control over those divs you're mousing over

:3